# Application not responding after adding Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I want to integrate Firebase into my Android application. When I do so, I need to add com.google.gms.google-services version 9 into my app gradle.

After testing it a few times and opening my app a couple of times, some times my app becomes not responding after start (the view has not even been created).

So, I tried to revert back the com.google.gms.google-services to version 7.5, which is the version I used before adding Firebase. Then, my application works normally just like before.

This is the gradle module file of my application (after reverting back to gms version 7.5)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
//    compileSdkVersion 23
//    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pasarumah.androidapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.6"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.7'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')
}
```

I've searched and seems someone has the same issue with me:
[Android app not responding](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/229)

Comment: are you still experiencing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need this of your project grade

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

And this  at the bottom of you module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In your code you don't have the apply plugin after your dependencies

Comment: I've done your suggestion, but I still experience the same thing. I try to open and close my app a few times, still the app is not responding some times.