# ANR with FCM and build variants with applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have issue with build variants and FCM.

I have defined 3 variants: dev,qa,release

```
dev/qa have applicationIdSuffix '.dev'

release has no suffix
```

**google-services.json** file has both package names properly defined and I read that google-services plugin reads it automatically during build process.

When I launch the dev variant, everything works just fine. But after that if I switch to release variant and try to launch that the app just hangs giving following trace:

> ANR in xxx
>
> Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT flg=0x14 cmp=xxx/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver (has extras) }

Dev variant works always, but staging variant also hangs in the start.

Possible related issues:

[Application not responding after adding Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625747/application-not-responding-after-adding-firebase)

NOTE: I also tested debug variant with exact same config staging variant has and it worked. So Gradle do something different with debug variant because there are no problems with that.

Any ideas how to fix this? Is this because of Android Studio or maybe some wrong configuration in gradle? Colleague has never seen this issue when he builds the app.

I also tried to remove android studio and reinstall it, also removed the project and pulled the source again, but the error still happens with my laptop.

Thanks.

NOTE: I rebooted my laptop, and run clean assemble from the terminal, all of the variants now seem to work. I noticed that sometimes when building directly from Android studio it seems that the application kinda starts in parts and then it gets removed which then causes the FCM receiver to hang up because the app just got removed. Is this some configuration of Android studio?

**CONCLUSION**

Didn't find the actual reason of my Android Studio / Laptop / Gradle setup which caused this, but if you encounter the same issue. Try rebooting your computer, re-cloning app project might help, also building variant from command line with clean option can also help instead of building it with Android studio.

Comment: post code this way we can't help

Comment: So, the exact same project normally build on another(collegue's) machine?

Comment: @azizbekian yes same project so it has to do something with android studio settings/idea files/something else

Comment: Have you tried `Invalidate cache & restart`?

Comment: @azizbekian yes, it didn't help

Comment: Same gradle and android gradle plugin versions? Same values in global `gradle.properties` file?

Comment: @azizbekian yes, same project and same android studio + gradle versions

Comment: gradle.properties are identical as well.

Comment: Try using `./gradlew clean assemble` in the terminal as it will build your project without relying on anything that Android Studio might do.

Comment: @JordyLangen no difference :S I will have to start building a fresh project and include piece by piece to see when/if this starts to happen again with my laptop.

Comment: @JordyLangen After I rebooted my laptop and then ran clean assemble I got the variants to work. So is it somehow possible that Android studio somehow messed up gradle daemons here? Is there some sort of hook to configure to gradle that it will always clean project when variant is changed ?

Comment: @Niko Please check your manifest file and see you implemented two services for FCM.

Comment: @Niko Please try to change the FCM version if you face the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Implement both this services in your manifest file.

```
    <service android:name="com.test.notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="com.test.notification.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Yes I have those both set, I have a feeling that this issue has something do with android studio/gradle cache and it also required me to restart my laptop to finally get the build working again normally.

Comment: Okey.Try to change your fcm dependency version.Also upgrade the gradle version if you are using old version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
apply plugin: com.google.gms.google-services
```

to the end of the build.gradle
and

```
compile com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:x.x.x
```

top of dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:x.x.x'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```